# How can I use this string to read dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, string, ip

I have this string. How can I read out the ip and the fw data?

```
new_string = b'{"data":[{"ip":"103.170.120.105","fw":"443"},
                        {"ip":"185.181.217.91","fw":"204"},
                        {"ip":"135.203.68.159","fw":"105"}]}'
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JSON module, or ast.literal_eval if you want to go that route.

Using JSON,

```
import json

new_string = b'{"data":[{"ip":"103.170.120.105","fw":"443"},{"ip":"185.181.217.91","fw":"204"},{"ip":"135.203.68.159","fw":"105"}]}'

# If you're using Python3, you may need to do this:
new_string = new_string.decode('utf-8')

json_string = json.loads(new_string)
data = json_string['data']

for item in data:
  # your ip and fw will be accessible
  # as item['ip'] and item['fw']

  print item['ip'], item['fw']
```

Using ast.literal_eval:

```
import ast

new_string = b'{"data":[{"ip":"103.170.120.105","fw":"443"},{"ip":"185.181.217.91","fw":"204"},{"ip":"135.203.68.159","fw":"105"}]}'

# If you're using Python3, you may need to do this:
new_string = new_string.decode('utf-8')

my_dictionary = ast.literal_eval(new_string)
data = my_dictionary['data']

for item in data:
  # your ip and fw are accessible the same way as above
  print item['ip'], item['fw']
```